# Uploading app with Xcode 7.1 issues multiple error: ERROR ITMS-90062

Tags: ios, xcode

I updated to Xcode 7.1 today. When I upload the archive to iTunes store, I got the following error. I don't understand why it repeats 5 times with different CFBundleShortVersionString(0.1.1, 0.6.2, 1.0.8, 0.4.1 and 0.9.13). I don't know where these numbers come from.

My current archive version # is 2.0 and Build # is 6.0. I did uploaded to iTunes Store 4 other versions before to testflight. All of them has version # 2.0, but build # are from 1 to 4. I am not sure if these are related. I don't have problem to upload the achieve with Xcode 7.0.

[image]

Please let me know how to fix the problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had something like this happen too.  XCode 7.1 made a change so that all included frameworks must have the same version as your main app.  There is a workaround via cocoapods here that may help.

https://github.com/Jonge/Cocoapods-frameworks-version-number-fix

[Apple's rather sparse notes can be found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2420/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016603-CH1-WATCHKIT_APPS_AND_APPS_WITH_SUB_FRAMEWORKS), you will need to scroll to the "WatchKit apps and apps with sub-frameworks" section.

Comment: I think it may be an iTunes Connect issue because I get the same errors submitting a build with either Xcode 7.01 or 7.1.